# Put shared library file in C++ project

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I'm looking to use an .so library in a C++ project of mine. I have the header file for it and the actual .so has to be somewhere as well; I installed [them](http://augeas.net/libfa/) using apt-get.

Since my project is under version management and I don't want everyone who downloads the repository to have to install the packages I installed, I would like to simply put the .so file and the header file somewhere in my project and only use those. Never having learned C++ properly, I don't know how I can do this.

If I have an .so library and the header file for it, how do I put them in a folder of my chosing and include them in my source code?

Comment: My advice is: Don't. Instead tell the users that if they want to build your project from source, they need library this and that. Then for the release of binaries you build static executable, that link statically with the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- You build with a static version of the library so you don't have such or problem.
- You tell the user to install the library
- You manually load the library, so you have your own search path for it (typically, current folder).

The last solution matches the most what you want, put may be quite difficult to set-up. There exist several library to easily load a .so file also.

Comment: Hm, none of them seem as straightforward as I would expect this to be. How come this is not something commonly done?

Comment: Because it is highly un-portable, mainly. But also because UNIX (and UNIX-likes) prefer shared objects to be system-wide objects. Hence the name, 'shared object.' It's not like Windows where they're simply called Dynamic Link Libraries.

Comment: Most application are installed using packages, so all dependencies are automatically managed. Also, this can easily be done in big application using the last solution I gave